# Can't view JS API Response on web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

First of all I am pretty new to working with APIs & JS.

I have created the following Get Request using PostMan and it returns the expected results perfectly in a JSON response.

```
<script>
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic NWFmZTBmOTAtMzQ4MC00ZDQ3LTgyMDYtMzUyOTgxNWE2MTBhOg==",
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "f69f3ecb-2e0c-4fcc-9cfa-796115805319,6cd343e2-d8d8-412e-b505-34218c69adca",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Cookie": "__cfduid=d569febd387dab8f972be1c6b2e2bd4341570112246; jsSplitTestGroup=8; .ASPXANONYMOUS=DF9G8b4OJy1PLMCJfQ-MY2TYySziRwo3Bm2dh7UcE9XCMvpkGsIREQYCT0qhS28zfqtWcBrGFmyOWNvp7xrMpdntsx8vldDCHlF15cGeN8eqL4-iyRTCsBFEWaLYnFGpHT7Biw2",
    "Referer": "http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log();
});
</script>
```

Now when I pasted that into my .html page, no response is shown and no errors show in console.

How do I render the JSON response on the webpage?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: First, you are trying to console the output with a blank. 
it should be console.log(response);
Then, you need to parse your JSON value somewhere in the page.

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the callback using the debugger. Does it get called?

Comment: @arielb how do I parse the JSON value?

Comment: @JakeFeeley it depends on what value you want to show on your DOM.
But once you have the json, you should use some dom manipulation in your elements for parsing the values into them .